# How to reduce the itunes app size?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, ipa

When submitting an app to Apple, i noticed that even though the App bundle is 60 MB, the actual app that shows up on itunes is 54 MB. However, when making the Ad Hoc build, the ipa is only 30 MB.

My understanding is that this is due to DRM that Apple has: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1795/_index.html

However, is there a better way to bypass this DRM that Apple puts?

Answer (score 1):

Apple just came up with a solution where if you add all your resources (images, videos, etc) to the so called **Assets catalog** file ***AND*** configure each file according to the device type being used ***THEN*** you can dramatically reduce app size.

Think about it! You have 3 copies of every image: img.png img@2x.png and img@3x.png
Then why would you need to have the non-retina set of images on a retina device?

And this answers why you see lower app size when you build. xCode does this automatically, but you can fine tune in assets catalog. Here is how:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/CustomizingImageSetsforSizeClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013303-CH10-SW1

Oh yeah, not only app size reduces! Apple made seamless integration to make the AppStore downloadable app be smaller. By making a custom build for every kind of device. Just use the Assets :)